# Hubstaff screenshots -- what about virtual desktops?

Tags: screenshot, virtual-desktop

Does anyone know if Hubstaff screenshots will monitor active virtual desktops, not just the desktop that the widget is on?  I am required by work to have screenshots enabled, but work remotely and don't want to close each application each time I clock in.  I'm running Linux, Lubuntu 20.04LTS.